# Android Textview resource not found

Tags: java, android, xml

Trying to get a grasp on android throught The big nerd ranch guide, i came across this example:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
```

where mQuestionBank

```
 private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
        new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
};
```

and those have been defined in strings.xml

```
<string name="question_oceans">The Pacific Ocean is larger than the Atlantic Ocean.</string>
<string name="question_mideast">The Suez Canal connects the Red Sea and the Indian Ocean.</string>
<string name="question_africa">The source of the Nile River is in Egypt.</string>
<string name="question_americas">The Amazon River is the longest river in the Americas.</string>
<string name="question_asia">Lake Baikal is the world\'s oldest and deepest freshwater lake.</string>
```

However I'm getting a Resource not found Exception.
(textResId is the first field of the question class)

EDIT:

Question Class

```
public class Question {
private int mTextResId;
private boolean mAnswerTrue;

public Question(int mTextResId, boolean mAnswerTrue) {
    mTextResId=mTextResId;
    mAnswerTrue=mAnswerTrue;
}

public int getTextResId() {
    return mTextResId;
}

public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
    mTextResId = textResId;
}

public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
    return mAnswerTrue;
}

public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
    mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
}
```

Comment: what is mCurrentIndex?

Comment: post your logcat output

Comment: mCurrentIndex is a private int = 0

Comment: Try this and let me know the result.
mQuestionTextView.setText(getResources().getString(question ));

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know the result. `mQuestionTextView.setText(getResources().getString(question));`

Also change the constructor section of the Question class

```
public Question(int mTextResId, boolean mAnswerTrue) {
    this.mTextResId=mTextResId;
    this.mAnswerTrue=mAnswerTrue;
}
```

Comment: This result in the same output.

Comment: Please share share the "Question" class too

Comment: Please change the constructer in Question class

public Question(int mTextResId, boolean mAnswerTrue) {
    this.mTextResId=mTextResId;
    this.mAnswerTrue=mAnswerTrue;
}

Comment: That was it! Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Standard code:

Use String array in yout String.xml file

```
  <string-array name="questions">
    <item>The Pacific Ocean is larger than the Atlantic Ocean.</item>
    <item>The Suez Canal connects the Red Sea and the Indian Ocean.</item>
    <item>The source of the Nile River is in Egypt.</item>
    <item>The Amazon River is the longest river in the Americas.</item>
    <item>Lake Baikal is the world\'s oldest and deepest freshwater lake.</item>
</string-array>
```

Now use below code in your java class

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
String[] mQuestionBank = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
String question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex];
mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each argument to the constructor shadows one of the object's fields — inside the constructor of Question class, **mTextResId** is a local copy of the constructor's first argument & **mAnswerTrue** is a local copy of the constructor's second argument.

To refer to the **Question** field **mTextResId**, the constructor must use **this.mTextResId** && **this.mAnswerTrue**. Try

```
public Question(int mTextResId, boolean mAnswerTrue) {
    this.mTextResId = mTextResId;
    this.mAnswerTrue = mAnswerTrue;
}
```